# matrix manipulation using Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array

New learner here, I need some help with matrix manipulation.

Let's say I have matrix A: 3x4, I need to reshape this into matrix B: 12x1.

The values in the 1st row of A would be the 1st 4 value in B, 2nd row in A would be in columns 5-8 in B...etc.

Please see picture for detail.

My real project involves images or 1000 x 1000 x 3 matrices, so I would need the solution to scale.

For illustration:

[image]

Comment: You probably want [`ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html). Please don't include screenshots the the data, the question should be self-contained.

Comment: Something like `arr.ravel().reshape(-1, 1)`

Comment: Hi Rogan, thanks for the help, I just wasn't sure I explained the question clearly, so I added an image for better visualization

Comment: You can even just drop `ravel`. I got going on a different line of thought. This is literally just a reshape. `arr.reshape(-1, 1)`. `-1` in the `reshape` is basically "fix this dimension for me because I don't know what it will be" and in this case, it can only be 1 because you're specifying as many rows as there are data points.

Answer (score 0):

numpy is a good option for working with arrays

```
import numpy as np
data = range(1,13)
basic_array = np.array(data).reshape(3,4)
wanted_array = basic_array.reshape(-1,1)
```

this works with pictures as well

Comment: They already have a numpy array, and you're hard-coding the dimensions which will lead to problems as soon as you try apply this approach to any other problem that isn't strictly confined.

Comment: You should use `-1` in your reshape to leave one dimension open